# Check on a rostopic programatically?

Tags: ros, rostopic-echo, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've tried searching for this but have been unsuccessful so far.

Is it possible to see a topic's value, programatically?
Basically, I need the functionality of rostopic echo, but I need to add it to my code.

It's a topic that I created myself, so I can't just create a client and call a service...
And I also do not want to subscribe to the topic and create a callback function.
I just want to know the topic's value at a given point in my code.

Is this possible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192902/check-on-a-rostopic-programatically?/) by [an](https://answers.ros.org/users/20206/an/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-09-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In C++, you can use `ros::topic::waitForMessage()`: http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/roscpp/html/namespaceros_1_1topic.html

Note that this will be slow, because internally it creates a subscriber, waits for it to connect, waits for the first message, and then removes the subscriber.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1